# Searching through many arrays to see if any of the name matches another var?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

Hey I'm trying to make a function that creates an alert if the name of an array of images matches the data attribute of the selected element. This is simply a test before I move forward with my actual plans but I'm stuck here. My confusion is twofold.

Note: Sorry, I am new to javascript, please bear with me.

1)How do I compare the name of an array with a var?

2)How do I search through all of the arrays present, do I need to make nested arrays, or another function for that? idk

My webpage have an undetermined amount of modal images which , when clicked, open a slideshow album of images. I got this working for 1 image then realized that to have it work for an undetermined amount of slideshows of undetermined size I should make a function that fills the slideshow div. I planned to have each modal image to have a data attribute of "1,2,3...etc" and have a bunch of arrays with the images each named similarly "1,2,3...etc" and if the names of both match up, then it will populate the slideshow with the images in the array. This way If i need to add another modal image all i need to do is give it the appropriate id and add an array of its images. I hope this was clear, if not then I will provide more clarification.

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img id="modal-1" src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="max-width:100%" data-modal="1" onclick="/*openModal();currentSlide(1);*/ fillSlides(this);" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
 function fillSlides(modalID){
    var slides_1 = ["Images/LS_01.jpg", "Images/LS_02.jpg", "Images/LS_03.jpg", "Images/LS_04.jpg" ];
 var slides_2 = ["Images/LS_05.jpg", "Images/LS_06.jpg", "Images/LS_07.jpg", "Images/LS_08.jpg" ];
var slides_3 = ["Images/LS_09.jpg", "Images/LS_10.jpg", "Images/LS_11.jpg", "Images/LS_12.jpg" ];

    var modal_num = modalID.getAttribute('data-modal');
    alert(modal_num);

    }
```

Comment: `(someArray.indexOf('testValue')!=-1)` you are only showing 1 array so I cannot make a version for multiple arrays

Comment: Do you mean that if `data-modal="1"` you want `LS_01.jpg` because it has a `1` in it?

Comment: @Barmar No I mean i want to match it with the name of the array, I have made an edit with multiple arrays.

Comment: Arrays don't have names. Do you mean the variable name?

Comment: Any time you want to deal with variable names dynamically, you should be using an object that maps names to values.

Comment: Yes @Barmar I mean the variable name of the array. for example slides_1 is the name for the array containing LS_01 - LS_04

Comment: @GeorgeCampbell I have edited it so it has many arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an object that maps the data you want to the array of images:

```
var slides = {
    "1": ["Images/LS_01.jpg", "Images/LS_02.jpg", "Images/LS_03.jpg", "Images/LS_04.jpg" ],
    "2": ["Images/LS_05.jpg", "Images/LS_06.jpg", "Images/LS_07.jpg", "Images/LS_08.jpg" ],
    "3": ["Images/LS_09.jpg", "Images/LS_10.jpg", "Images/LS_11.jpg", "Images/LS_12.jpg" ]
};
```

Then you can use `slides[modal_num]` to get the slides for the images that was clicked.

Comment: Thank you very much I didn't know this could be done. I will try it out and hopefully it works.

Comment: How would I go further and extract the actual images? In my code I will be creating (within my slideshow container) a div.mySlides for every image. So how would I go about accessing each individual image?

Comment: Assign `slides[modal_num]` to a variable, then loop over it.

Comment: `slides[modal_num][i]` accesses the i'th image in the array.

Comment: This is all basic Javascript syntax, nothing complicated. An array is an array, it doesn't matter where it comes from.

Comment: I've made an attempt at this but it doesn't seem to be working, If you could check it out I'd appreciate it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47168540/javascript-trying-to-add-images-to-slideshow-with-js-but-it-doesnt-work  . My best guess is that data attribute is a string and not an int so it won't work, but idk how to fix that.