# Delete all Elements in a class EXCEPT two anchor tags

Tags: javascript, html

Hey I have made a function that fills an empty container of a slideshow with images, with each image being contained in it's own div.

My webpage has an undetermined amount of modal images which , when clicked, open a slideshow album of images. I got this working for 1 image then realized that to have it work for an undetermined amount of slideshows of undetermined size I should make a function that fills the slideshow div. I planned to have each modal image to have a data attribute of "1,2,3...etc" and have a bunch an array with multiple objects each named similarly "1,2,3...etc" then I'd use this information to create and append the correct divs and images to the slideshow container.

I have successfully done this but I THINK I need to clear the parent .modal-content div of all it's children EXCEPT the two buttons (.next and .prev), because the modal seems to open the correct slideshow, but only on the first time it is clicked, the other times it just keeps adding more and more of the array to it. I believe clearing the div upon closing the slideshow should fix this IF IN FACT IT COMPLETELY GETS RID OF THE INNER ELEMENTS, which I think my code should do but I got it off of stackoverflow so idk for certain.

I have this code to delete the content of the div (Note this is really where I need to add the code that excludes those 2 elements, but I've included more code for context):

```
function clearSlides(){

    var myNode = document.getElementById("modal_content");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
      myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild);
    }
  }
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img id="modal-1" src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="max-width:100%" data-modal="1" onclick="fillSlides(this); openModal(); currentSlide(1); " class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="clearSlides(); closeModal();">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content" id="modal_content">

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

.modal-content div get's filled with this js function:

```
  function fillSlides(modalID){
    var container = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content");

    var slides = {
      "1": ["Images/LS_01.jpg", "Images/LS_02.jpg", "Images/LS_03.jpg", "Images/LS_04.jpg" ],
      "2": ["Images/LS_05.jpg", "Images/LS_06.jpg", "Images/LS_07.jpg", "Images/LS_08.jpg" ],
      "3": ["Images/LS_09.jpg", "Images/LS_10.jpg", "Images/LS_11.jpg", "Images/LS_12.jpg" ]
    };
    var modal_num = modalID.getAttribute('data-modal');
    //alert(slides[modal_num].length);

    for (var i = 0 ; i < slides[modal_num].length; i++) {
      var the_divs = document.createElement('div');
      var s_img = document.createElement('img');

      the_divs.className = 'mySlides';

      s_img.src = slides[modal_num][i];

      the_divs.appendChild(s_img);

      container[0].appendChild(the_divs);
    }
  }
```

Please let me know if further clarification is required.

Comment: Change `var container = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-content");` to `var container = document.querySelector('.modal-container')` and `container[0].appendChild(the_divs);` to `container.appendChild(the_divs)`

Comment: Keep your control arrows outside of `.column` and use `innerHTML = ""` to clear the inside of `.column`

Comment: I'm not trying to clear .column, I'm trying to clear .modal-content

Comment: Ok then keep your controls outside of `.modal-content` and `innerHTML = ''` the `.modal-content`. Your controls look like they are independent, so repositioning them in layout shouldn't be much of an adjustment

Comment: Thanks this works, But my issue now is that since I was using top: 50%; in my css to have the controls be in the middle and to the side, and since top positions in reference to it's container it isn't in middle anymore. Is there anyway i can set these controls to the top:50% of the modal-content div, without having them be inside the div itself?

Comment: I forgot to make the first change you suggested but it still worked, could you perhaps explain why I need to change that, is it an efficiency thing?

Comment: It's in anticipation that you may need to dynamically remove or add modals in the future. The old methods like `getElementsBy*` return a "live" collection so if you change the HTMLCollection it will do so immediately. It sounds good in your head, *but* it isn't when you are using a loop that references the `.length` in order to stop. Every loop the `.length` would change and the end result is usually that the loop stops halfway. `querySelectorAll()` returns a static NodeList so the `.length` is constant in loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per comments keep your controls outside of `#modal_content` use `innerHTML=''` to wipe everything within it.

### Demo

```js
function clearSlides() {
  var content = document.getElementById('modal_content');

  content.innerHTML = '';
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img id="modal-1" src="https://www.yosemitehikes.com/images/wallpaper/yosemitehikes.com-bridalveil-winter-1200x800.jpg" style="max-width:100%" data-modal="1" onclick="fillSlides(this); openModal(); currentSlide(1); " class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="close cursor" onclick="clearSlides(); closeModal();">&times;</div>
  <div class="modal-content" id="modal_content">
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://chasingseals.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/greenlandBanner2000x800.jpg" class="img">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.catholicevangelism.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/1200x800.gif" class="img">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="http://www.a1carpet-to.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/08/600x400.png" class="img">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://support.kickofflabs.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/800x1200.png" class="img">
    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
```

Comment: Thank you this works. My issue now is that since I was using top: 50%; in my css to have the controls be in the middle and to the side, and since top positions in reference to it's container it isn't in middle anymore. Is there anyway i can set these controls to the top:50% of the modal-content div, without having them be inside the div itself?

Comment: If `#myModal` wraps around `.modal-content` tightly (`padding:0, display:table;position:relative`) then you can set arrows as `position:absolute, top:calc(50% - the height of close X button)`

Comment: It isnt tight though there is space. If there is no way to do this i suppose i must put it back into the div and find a way to only delete it if the class is not prev or next or something along those lines?

Comment: If it breaks your layout, then keep arrows in original spot and create the arrows inside of the `openModal()` function with [`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) it's `innerHTML` on steroids.

Comment: Okay thanks, Also is there no way to simply exclude certain elements from being erased? I'm still using    var myNode = document.getElementById("modal_content");
    while (myNode.firstChild) {
      myNode.removeChild(myNode.firstChild); 
    } cuz I've heard its faster. Is there no way to simply exclude certain elements because I want to add dots as well which will tell you how many images there are and where you are so far in the slideshow, and it'll be easier in the long run than deleting and adding them again

Comment: Using my original answer with https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/0z5ydwe0/ I got a better solution make `margin-top:-50px` to `margin-top:0`. Going either route you should have a function that generates `.mySlides` and its contents according to your array.

Comment: That works, do you know whether this will remain in the middle relative to the inner slideshow on larger windows as well? I have a 13" laptop. I ask because it seems to become slightly off when I make the window smaller

Comment: You'll need to adjust to the padding and borders of `#myModal` as well as the total height of the close button (that includes border and padding). margins are a factor if they are from sibling (ie close button.) Although it's a pain in the beginning, using relative measurements like % and em will payoff in the end. To this end [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) is your friend

Comment: Is there really no way to simply be within the for loop in clearSlides, be like (ignore the 100%incorrect syntaxt) if(node.firstchild.classname != prev && node.firstchild.classname != next &&node.firstchild.classname != ...etc){then delete all the stuff}

Comment: Sorry if that made no sense, I'm just trying to type out a theoretical idea in actual code that I don't know atm

Comment: Regardless of whether you have the controls on the inside or outside, you'll need to adjust for different screen sizes I believe. So it's best to keep everything separate from `.modal-content` anyhow.

Comment: Well not if I have it inside, because I have the height on my slideshow as a constant (90vh);

Comment: But is there a way to do as I mentioned? Because I believe that would be ideal, as It wold be benificial in the future when I add dots as well

Comment: If you concerned about future expansion, consider using `.addEventListener()` instead of inline event handlers (as recommended in my [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47169604/2813224)). There's [3 ways to handle events](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35093997/2813224) and there are certain limitations about your code that "fetters" you to one way of approaching your layout. Instead of destroying your layout, you could modify the attributes like the `img.src = arr[i]` and if the album has fewer or more slides, create them from a...

Comment: ... [clone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) or  [`<template>`](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/template/)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are adding class 'mySlides' to your slides, you can check if the element you are removing actually contains mySlides class. If it does not you should not remove it.

Also you can move buttons to a separate div. This would separate your slides and controls so it gives you more freedom to manipulate modal content.

Comment: How would I do that? Could you show me? What would i need to add to my existed clearSlides () method? Also would deleting mySlides delete the elements within it too, I assume so just want to confirm?

Comment: Okay I don't know whether it is working or not, I have created a fiddle in my post and made an edit further explaining my issue. https://jsfiddle.net/rpkxtqLz/ For some reason my fiddle's js won't run though. Anyways I don't think what you've posted works, or if it does I have another issue which I have no Idea what it is or how to fix it

Comment: I updated fiddle. Removed redundant picture at the beginning. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/2j57hz1f/1/) 
You can comment clearSlides function call to see the result of the function. Problem with your code is has runtime error. Your slides array is empty when you are calling showSlides function. So your modal_content never gets updated with images. But this is different issue to address than to clear content of your modal_content div.

Comment: Sorry I see the js that you have posted but your fiddle doesn't seem to do anything? it's just 2 arrows and an X.

Comment: This is just a demonstration of clearing slides in your model_content element. It does not have any extra functionality since from the topic I understand you have a problem with clearing slides from a div with leaving two anchor tags inside. Which is exactly what this fiddle does.